# internet is not working in virtualbox linux(CentOS 7)

Tags: virtualbox, ping, centos7

Internet is not working in my virtual machine (CentOS 7)

I don't know where to start...
machine has two network adapter, NAT and Host 
I can ping among virtual machines such as "ping slave1" "ping slave2" .... it works just fine

1. ping 8.8.8.8

   -> PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

after this message, nothing comes out..

2. ping google.com

   -> no any message comes out for a while and it says "ping: unkown host google.com"
3. enp0s3 -> NAT(on)

   -> inet 10.0.2.15
   -> netmask 255.255.255.0
4. enp0s8 -> host(on)

   -> 192.168.56.101

Where should I start to figure it out?

Please I am spending more than 17 hours for this...

Comment: There is a companion site for this. Can you move this to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

The Netwrok adaptateur must be :

1. Enabled
2. Attached to Bridge Adapter

Then in the virtual machine, open the Network Connections configuration and configure to Obtain an IP address automatically and Obtain DNS server address automatically